# The mean of normal distribution (Central Limit Theorem Question)

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Given independent and identically distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$

We know that the random variable $Y=\frac{1}{n}\sum{X_i}$ is normally distributed (from the Central Limit Theorem)

Given this information, can we figure out the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ of this normal $Y$ random variable?
If not, what if we're given $\mathbb E(X_i)$ and $Var(X_i)$ $\forall i$  ? Can we find out then?

Comment: It is not true that $Y$ is normally distributed. What is true is $Y \to EX_1$ a.s. by SLLN.

Comment: $E(Y)=E(X_1)$ and $Var(Y)=\frac{Var(X_1)}{n}$ whenever $X_i$s are i.i.d with finite mean and variance.